# Log4cxx Error. Please initialize the log4cxx system properly

Tags: log4cxx, log4c

I´m running an application on a red hat image of docker. I have some .sh files but when executing them on the logs files I see this error:

```
Log4cxx  Please initialize the log4cxx system properly.
```

Log4cxx is already installed

Answer (score 1):

The .sh script must be invoking some C++ application that uses log4cxx and that application is not configuring log4cxx.

log4cxx is configured either by calling BasicConfigurator::configure() or by passing the path of a .properties to PropertyConfigurator::configure or a .xml file to DOMConfigurator::configure.

Try setting the LOG4CXX_CONFIGURATION environment variable to the path of a configuration file containing a configuration. See [Example configurations](https://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/latest_stable/configuration-samples.html#xml-example-1)